# JDOM2 - two Namespaces

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jdom-2

I am trying to build the following XML structure:

```
<EDIOrderPackage xmlns="urn:URI" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <Test>true</Test>
</EDIOrderPackage>
```

I use JDOM2 and don't know how to add 2 Namespaces!
Even if I set only one Namespace the result is not the same as I wish it to be.
If I set the Namespace by `root.setNamespace()` and use the 2nd one with the prefix i it looks like this:

```
<i:EDIOrderPackage mlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <Test>true</Test>
<i:/EDIOrderPackage>
```

So there is an i before the EDIPOrderPackage.

If i dont use a prefix is looks like this:

```
<EDIOrderPackage xmlns="urn:URI">
    <Version xmlns="">1.0.0.0</Version>
    <Test xmlns="">true</Test>
</EDIOrderPackage>
```

If if try to add it as attributes, it throws the error message that I cannot an attribute with the name "xmlns"

So how can I build an XML with JDOM looking like the one above?

Answer (score 4):

The trick is that, with Namespaces, you have to specify it correctly for all elements you add.

Additionally, a default Namespace is one that is declared as `xmlns="...."` and not `xmlns:abc="...."`

When you use a default namespace, it has no 'prefix' on the elements. So from your example code you have:

- The default namespace: `xmlns="urn:URI"`
- The 'i' namespace:      `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

You can create these with JDOM as:

```
Namespace nsDefault = Namespace.getNamespace("urn:URI");
Namespace nsI = Namespace.getNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Now, when you create your elements, you have to put them in the right Namespaces:

```
Element root = new Element("EDIOrderPackage", nsDefault);
Element version = new Element("Version", nsDefault);
Element test = new Element("Test", nsDefault);

root.addNamespaceDeclaration(nsI); // add the i namespace declaration.
root.addContent(version);
root.addContent(test);
```

If you add the XMLOutputter aspect of things:

```
Document doc = new Document(root);
XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
xout.output(doc, System.out);
```

the above code produces the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EDIOrderPackage xmlns="urn:URI" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Version />
  <Test />
</EDIOrderPackage>
```